# R shiny stop scrolling to top of page after changing input

Tags: r, input, scroll, shiny, dt

I have created a datatable in an R shiny app at the top of the page with input controls at the bottom that determine the data displayed in that table.

The table is long, and the user must therefore scroll down to access the input controls. But upon changing any single input control, the app will automatically scroll to the top of the page.

How can I prevent automatic scrolling to the top of the page when changing the inputs? (Note that I do not want to delay updating of the table until all inputs are changed by having, for example, an 'Update table' button that must be clicked, in which case automatic scrolling would be OK.)

Note that this hasn't worked for me:
[R shiny: how to stop sliderInput label click from causing scroll to top of page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048303/r-shiny-how-to-stop-sliderinput-label-click-from-causing-scroll-to-top-of-page)

Example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Define UI
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           DT::dataTableOutput("exampleOutput"),
           numericInput("var", h5("Row value"), value = 100)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  exampleTable <- reactive({
    transactionCostsDataFrame <- data.frame(
      "Transaction" = rep(input$var, 100))
  })

  output$exampleOutput <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(exampleTable(), escape = FALSE, 
                  options = list(dom = "t", ordering = FALSE, 
                                 bFilter = 0, pageLength = 100))
    )
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: could you please supply a minimal working example

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your interest in my question. Example code added.