# R Shiny Making Action Button Scroll to the Top of the next Tab

Tags: shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

For a shinyapp which I have been working on, The 'Continue' buttons at the bottom of the app all end up going to the middle or bottom of the next tab. Is there a way to make the button not only change the tab, but also scroll back up to the top of the tab?

Here is the code from my server:
  `observeEvent(input$Cont1, { updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = 'subtabs',selected = 'med') })`

and from my UI:
`actionButton("Cont1", label = "Continue", style = 'height:50px; width:100px;margin-bottom:10px; font-size:120%; border: 1px solid #5A94C0; background-color: white'),`

The above code is successful at moving to the correct tab, but not for moving to the correct part of the tab. I have tried the solution proposed in: [R shiny stop scrolling to top of page after changing input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50206649/r-shiny-stop-scrolling-to-top-of-page-after-changing-input), but still have not found success.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will increase the likelihood of getting an answer if you provide a [full(!) reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).